# tableToJSON headers mismatch D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

When hardcoding a table in my body the jquery plugin tableToJSON() fetches the correct headers from my table. However, when I build this exact table in d3 it for some reason uses the first line in the body as headers. The peculiar part is I used a jquery html string export to hardcode the HTML. How can this be?

I made a code pen showing my problem. When opening an alert is shown showcasing the different header columns/keys used by these two approaches

https://codepen.io/keesbaake/pen/JwZeJg

So what happens is that these two give different results although the string representation in html is both exported from the d3 generated table:

```
$('#normal_table').tableToJSON()
$('#d3_table').tableToJSON()
```

I have looked for ages and don't even know what my exact problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The JSON specification dictates the properties are not ordered.  What that means for you is that you **can not** guarantee the order when you call `Object.keys`.  Not sure what your ultimate goal is but you'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: The reason I use Object.keys is just to alert the user with the difference in keys when constructing a JSON through harcoding the table or constructing the table programatically through d3.

Comment: If you inspect the `d3` parsed data (after it converts the csv data to JSON), you'll observe a columns property: `columns: ["No.", "Nation", "Games", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze", "Total"]`, this is what the `d3` code is using to order the columns (unlike properties, a JSON array by spec is guaranteed to be ordered).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, what happened is that when you hardcode a thead and immediately supply th child elements, then somehow the html in the source code first adds a tr element between thead and th.

When doing this straight away from d3, the table looks exactly the same however it does not have this explicit tr element. Therefore, the tableToJSON function fails to notice the header.

I would love to know why this happens though. Is there some sort of postprocessor for html in the browser on loading?